# React Timer re-render many times,how to solve it?

Tags: reactjs

The seconds counts 2, it renders 1,2,The seconds counts 3, it renders 1,2,3. Why does this render many times and also timeout doesn't work? Did I miss something?

```
const Timer = () => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  var interval;
  useEffect(() => {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds + 1);
      console.log("seconds", seconds);
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() => clearInterval(interval), 5000);
  }, [seconds]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>{seconds}</div>
    </>
  );
};
export default Timer;
```

Answer (score 2):

there is an issue in your setInterval, Inside the setInterval function update the state using the previous state by passing a function to setSeconds. This ensures that you're correctly incrementing the seconds counter.

```
function Timer() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(5);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((prevSeconds) => prevSeconds + 1);
    }, 1000);

    // Clear the interval after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }, 5000);

    // Clean up the interval when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{seconds}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Timer;
```

update your useEffect like this

Comment: mark this as correct if it works for you